# Python Pandas read_excel and to_json date format error

Tags: javascript, python, json, date, pandas

Below is the data from an excel which I am trying to convert to JSON using pandas `read_excel` and `to_json` functions. The JSON date has the field `"Date"` as `1449446400000` (without quotes). I am wondering why the date is displayed as a big number instead of `12/7/2015`.

```
ID    Date      Name   Lat        Long     Pick Success Failure Drop Amount
===========================================================================
5   12/7/2015   PSG 11.0231335  77.0016396  31    21      10    44   5192
```

Please let me know how to convert it into a proper date format in JSON so that I can use to to generate some JavaScript charts.

Below is the code snippet;

```
def home(request):
    df = pandas.read_excel('<here goes the excel path>')
    json = df.to_json(orient="records")
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data':json})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `date_format` when writing to json with:

```
json = df.to_json(orient="records", date_format='iso')
```

Since the default is 'epoch', without setting it explicity to 'iso', you're getting your results in epoch milliseconds. This returns for a sample output:

```
'[{"id":5,"date":"2015-07-12T00:00:00.000Z"}]'
```