# Pandas duplicated index after dropping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, pivot

I'm getting: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

The data I'm working with is very huge, and I cannot provide sample data, nor can I not replicate the error with smaller set of data. I have tried to generate duplicates with dummy data to replicate my original frame but for some mysterious reason the code only works with the dummy data and not my real data. This is what I know of the shape I'm working with.

```
df.shape

>> (6820, 26) 

df.duplicated()

>> 0       False
>> 1       False
>> 2       False
>>        ...  
>> 6818    False
>> 6819    False
>> Length: 6820, dtype: bool
```

Now I want to find out which rows that are duplicates.

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

>> 0 rows × 26 columns
```

Just to make sure I'm dropping all the duplicates and only keep the first one:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

And this is when I'm getting the ValueError:

```
df2 = df.melt('Release')\
        .assign(variable = lambda x: x.variable.map({'Created Date':1,'Finished Date':-1}))\
        .pivot('value','Release','variable').fillna(0)\
        .rename(columns = lambda c: f'{c} netmov' )


---> 33         .pivot('value','Release','variable').fillna(0)\
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

From investigating further into it, it seems like it isn't the rows that are duplicates, but the index. I've tried to reset the index with df.reset_index() but it throws the same ValueError.

EDIT:

I can provide the dummy data that should replicate the frame I'm working with (just a couple of less columns that are not needed)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["Peter", "Anna", "Anna", "Peter", "Simon", "Johan", "Nils", "Oskar", "Peter"]
                  , 'Deposits': ["2019-03-07", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-12", "2019-03-12", "2019-03-14", "2019-03-07", "2019-03-08", "2016-03-07", "2019-03-07"]
                  , 'Withdrawals': ["2019-03-11", "2019-03-19", "2019-05-22", "2019-10-31", "2019-04-05", "2019-03-11", "NaN", "2017-03-06", "2019-03-11"]})

df.duplicated()

0    False
1    False
2    False
.....
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool

df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
df2 = df.melt('name')\
        .assign(variable = lambda x: x.variable.map({'Deposits':1,'Withdrawals':-1}))\
        .pivot('value','name','variable').fillna(0)\
        .rename(columns = lambda c: f'{c} netmov' )

df2 = pd.concat([df2,df2.cumsum().rename(columns = lambda c: c.split()[0] + ' balance')], axis = 1)\
        .sort_index(axis=1)


print(df2.head())

name        Anna balance  Anna netmov  Johan balance  Johan netmov  \
value                                                                
2016-03-07           0.0          0.0            0.0           0.0   
2017-03-06           0.0          0.0            0.0           0.0   
2019-03-07           0.0          0.0            1.0           1.0   
2019-03-08           1.0          1.0            1.0           0.0   
2019-03-11           1.0          0.0            0.0          -1.0
```

This will run smoothly, even though there are duplicates in the DataFrame.

Preferably I don't want to drop duplicates as well, because "Anna" could have made 4 deposits and 4 withdrawals during a day, so I want to count all of those.

The dataframe I'm working with:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.drop(['id'], axis=1)
df

Output:

        name    Deposits     Withdrawals
0       Anna    2020-07-31   NaN
1       Peter   2020-07-30   NaN
2       Simon   2020-07-30   NaN
3       Simon   2020-07-29   NaN
4       Simon   2020-07-29   NaN
... ... ... ...
6154    Peter   2014-01-22  2014-02-03
6155    Peter   2014-01-22  2014-01-29
6156    Peter   2014-01-22  2014-01-24
6157    Peter   2014-01-21  2014-01-29
6158    Peter   2014-01-15  2014-02-03
6159 rows × 3 columns
```

Update: Shout-out to the community for helping me solve this.

This solved the issue:

```
df.Deposits = pd.to_datetime(df.Deposits)
df.Withdrawals = pd.to_datetime(df.Withdrawals)

df2 = (
    df.melt('name') 
    .assign(variable = lambda x: x.variable.map({'Deposits':1,'Withdrawals':-1}))
    .dropna(subset=['value']) # you need this for cases like Nils's Withdrawal
    )
df2 = df2.groupby(['value', 'name']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).droplevel(0, axis=1)


df2 = (
    pd.concat([df2, df2.cumsum()], keys=['netmov', 'balance'], axis=1)
     notice how concat has the functionality you want for naming columns
     and is a better idea to have netmov/balance in a separate level
     in case you want to groupby or .loc later on
    .reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
    )
```

Stumble upon next problem though, unrelated to this. When converting this DataFrame to json, it will convert the dates into another format for some reason.

```
data = df2.to_json()
print(data)

{
    "Peter":
    {
        "1389744000000": 0,
        "1390262400000": 0,
        "1390348800000": 0,
        "1390521600000": 0,
    .....
    .....
    }
}
```

It's always something else, heh.. cheers for the help though, I can almost touch the goal-line.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your data/dataframe structure looks like ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `.reset_index()` just in case?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a few variations:

df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index() with drop and inplace
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) with drop and inplace

Comment: I'm reading in the data from a csv file, there are 26 columns but the only ones relevant for this timeline I'm trying to create is the columns: ['id'], ['name'], ['Deposits'], ['Withdrawals']. In the sample data I took data from the original csv-file.

Comment: This csv-file also contains multiple rows with identical ids in the ['id']-column. Those I am dropping.

Comment: Posted a sample of the real data, not sure if that is helpful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be arise when a name has multiple movements in exactly the same Deposit/Withdrawal dates (hence the duplicates). Dataframe `.pivot` method cannot handle duplicate indexes, it's just not designed for that. For the purpose of your analysis `.pivot_table` will do the trick, the main difference being that this one can apply an aggregation function to handle duplicate indexes (sum in this case). https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html

I personally tend to use `.groupby` with any problems of the sort because it offers the functionality of grouping not only by any combination of columns in df, but can also include exogenous series, calculations, index or levels of index of self or other, masks, etc.

So my code for this would be:

```
df.Deposits = pd.to_datetime(df.Deposits)
df.Withdrawals = pd.to_datetime(df.Withdrawals) # this parsing probably happens in read_csv
df2 = (
    df.melt('name') 
    .assign(variable = lambda x: x.variable.map({'Deposits':1, 'Withdrawals':-1}))
    # use lambda if you must
    # replace on 'variable' after creating df2 would also work
    # and is probably faster for larger dfs
    .dropna(subset=['value']) # you need this for cases like Nils's Withdrawal
    )
df2 = df2.groupby(['value', 'name']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).droplevel(0, axis=1)
df2 = (
    pd.concat([df2, df2.cumsum()], keys=['netmov', 'balance'], axis=1)
    # notice how concat has the functionality you want for naming columns
    # and is a better idea to have netmov/balance in a separate level
    # in case you want to groupby or .loc later on
    .reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
    )
```

Output

```
name          Anna          Johan           Nils  ...  Oskar   Peter          Simon
           balance netmov balance netmov balance  ... netmov balance netmov balance netmov
value                                             ...
2016-03-07       0      0       0      0       0  ...      1       0      0       0      0
2017-03-06       0      0       0      0       0  ...     -1       0      0       0      0
2019-03-07       0      0       1      1       0  ...      0       2      2       0      0
2019-03-08       1      1       1      0       1  ...      0       2      0       0      0
2019-03-11       1      0       0     -1       1  ...      0       0     -2       0      0
2019-03-12       2      1       0      0       1  ...      0       1      1       0      0
2019-03-14       2      0       0      0       1  ...      0       1      0       1      1
2019-03-19       1     -1       0      0       1  ...      0       1      0       1      0
2019-04-05       1      0       0      0       1  ...      0       1      0       0     -1
2019-05-22       0     -1       0      0       1  ...      0       1      0       0      0
2019-10-31       0      0       0      0       1  ...      0       0     -1       0      0
```

Comment: Again, you saved my day (week)! This works perfectly fine! I removed the last part with netmov, but it was a good feature to check the values. Now I'm just gonna have to figure out why the dates gets a weird value when converting to a json.

data = df2.to_json() will convert the dates into another format.

{"Peter":{"1389744000000":0,"1390262400000":0,"1390348800000":0, ... ... }

Thank again for your help, upvoted!

Comment: You can pass dateformat argument to `to_json`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920479/6692898